# Nav bar text spills over when sidebar collapse to icons

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a sidebar which contains icons and a menu name. Once the screen is smaller then x amount the sidebar collapses to show up only the icon and hide the menu name. 
The navbar is as follows:

```
<nav id="sidebar" [ngClass]="{active: barActive}">
        <div id="toogleIcon" (click)="onDismiss()">
            <img id="closeIcon" *ngIf="barActive" class="" src="../assets/img/icons/1.svg">
            <span id="menuIcon">
                <img *ngIf="!barActive" class="" src="../assets/img/icons/2.svg">
            </span>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="itemMenu" routerLink="/clients">
                    <img class="navItemsSvg" src="../assets/img/icons/A.svg">
                    <span *ngIf="barActive && !islargeDesktop() || islargeDesktop()" class="navTextItem">A</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="itemMenu" routerLink="/users">
                    <img class="navItemsSvg" src="../assets/img/icons/B.svg">
                    <span *ngIf="barActive && !islargeDesktop() || islargeDesktop()" class="navTextItem">B</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="itemMenu" routerLink="/houses">
                    <img class="navItemsSvg" src="../assets/img/icons/C.svg">
                    <span *ngIf="barActive && !islargeDesktop() || islargeDesktop()" class="navTextItem">C</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="itemMenu" routerLink="/devices">
                    <img class="navItemsSvg" src="../assets/img/icons/D.svg">
                    <span *ngIf="barActive && !islargeDesktop() || islargeDesktop()" class="navTextItem">D</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="itemMenu" routerLink="/administration">
                    <img class="navItemsSvg" src="../assets/img/icons/F.svg">
                    <span *ngIf="barActive && !islargeDesktop() || islargeDesktop()" class="navTextItem">F</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="barPlaceholder"></div>
```

You can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/36mjqc5v/

The problem I am facing is that when the sidebar collapses the menu name continues to display spilling out of the sidebar.

This seems to be an issue with the css properties. But I am unsure what is causing it.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to hide Menu names and show icons?

Comment: Yes, the menu names should not display while collapsed side bar

Comment: then simply use media query to hide the names like in your case, it should be 
`@media(max-width:600px){ .navTextItem{display:none;}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding media query in css, this can be accomplish

```
 @media(max-width:600px) /*specific width*/
    { .navTextItem{display:none;}}
```

Comment: You need to save it and it will generate a new link that you need to post. The link you sentdidn't contain the changes you did.